# WebService over c#/https .net 4.6.1 fails on W7 but works in .net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ssl, web, https

I have an app connecting to an Azure AppServer thorugh WebServices (using SoapHttpClientProtocol).

It was working perfectly on .NET 3.5sp1, when i upgraded to .NET 4.6.1, it works ok on w10 boxes, but some w7 or w8 fail with:

**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send**

If I modify the constructor adding:

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

it does works. But i want to use Tls1.2, instead of Ssl3. if i use

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

(or the default) it gives the error on the w7 and w8 boxes.

This is the list of ciphers presented to the server on the w10 (it works):

> CONNECT spac-test.cloudapp.net:443 HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   spac-test.cloudapp.net Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted
>   the parameters below.
>
> Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2) Random: 58 17 93 A5 5C 57 36 C2 97 69 48 B2 92
>   5C 93 44 86 1A 87 99 19 53 4D 04 C4 CB EE C0 87 70 30 67 "Time":
>   1/10/2058 1:26:48 AM SessionID: empty Extensions: 
>     server_name xxx.cloudapp.net
>        elliptic_curves  unknown [0x1D),
>   secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]    ec_point_formats    uncompressed
>   [0x0]
>        signature_algs   sha256_rsa, sha384_rsa, sha1_rsa, sha256_ecdsa,
>   sha384_ecdsa, sha1_ecdsa, sha1_dsa, sha512_rsa, sha512_ecdsa
>     SessionTicket   empty
>         extended_master_secret  empty
>     renegotiation_info  00
>
> Ciphers:
>     [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [009F]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [009E]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>     [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>     [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>     [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>     [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>     [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>     [0039]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
>     [0033]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA
>     [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>     [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
>     [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA     [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
>     [006A]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>     [0040]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
>     [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
>     [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
>
> Compression:      [00]    NO_COMPRESSION

... and here is what is being presented on the PC which DOES NOT WORK:

> A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted
>   the parameters below.
>
> Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2) Random: 58 17 97 37 8C 71 81 A2 0F 25 5F BE 3F
>   D1 37 8D B8 4C 4F D3 58 BF A5 C6 EB DE E7 C3 6B 74 5D 86 "Time":>
>      Ciphers:
>
> 22/07/1999 9:06:32 SessionID: empty Extensions: 
>     renegotiation_info  00
>     server_name xxxx.cloudapp.net
>     elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
>     ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
>     signature_algs  sha256_rsa,
>   sha384_rsa, sha1_rsa, sha256_ecdsa, sha384_ecdsa, sha1_ecdsa, sha1_dsa
>   [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA     [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>     [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA     [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>     [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
>     [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>     [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>     [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>     [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>     [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>     [0040]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
>     [006A]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>     [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
>     [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA   [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
>
> Compression:      [00]    NO_COMPRESSION

I suppose has something to do with the ciphers been negotiated, but will like to make w7 use tls1.2 (I check options in IE show "use Tls1.2", also instaled the registry settings to enable tls 1.2 in w7 :

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: Download IISCrypto and use it to quickly enable TLS.

Comment: I don't think that is the root cause, because when I use System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 in a Win10 client, it works ok.